# View showing Teasers - getting path for full content in teaser template

Tags: views, uri

I have created a simple view to list teasers of a particular content type.

I'm then using a simple view template, modified to suit the layout needed.
In the content type set-up there is not an option to display the path/URL to the full content. I can set the image if output to link to the original content, but I can't seem to find an option to just get the URL for the full content so I can link the whole teaser block to the full article.

Any clues? Know this should be easy - but can't seem to find it.

Comment: Normally, you can access nid with `$row->nid` in your template. From that, you can easily build the link to your node content with `node/ . $row->nid` path.

Comment: You know I was looking for a harder route - this makes perfect sense, and you're right (well $node->nid) is there in the loop. Do you want to pop this up as an answer? Thanks.

Comment: Done! Glad it helped you. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, you can access nid with `$row->nid` in your template.

From that, you can easily build the link to your node content with `node/ . $row->nid` path.